# MSVCP110.dll missing error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Well I have a program that can only run with the presence of MSVCP110.DLL, and as I have found out, I need to BUY Visual Studio 2012 just to run the program... Would anyone be able to point a noob in the right direction?

Comment: Have you contacted the original author? See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0fcf73a4-72a7-463a-a741-7cf4372ab208/can-msvcp110dll-and-msvcr110dll-be-shipped-with-applications; it appears to be free to distribute.

Comment: Even if it did require VS you can download the express versions freely.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is the DLL then Microsoft provide it in the [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679) .

Comment: I don't have Visual Studio, and I have tried this already. Same error keeps popping up.

Comment: EDIT- I realize I don't NEED Studio.

Comment: Try putting MSVCP110.DLL in the same location as the program?